# Badoo кликнуть по элементу на JS

Tags: javascript

На этой странице

https://badoo.com/encounters

Раньше работало программное нажатие на лайк:

```
document.querySelector('.profile-action--yes').click()
```

Потом перестало. Переехал на мобильную версию.
Через неделю и там закрыли такую возможность.

Пытался имитировать цепочку событий blur, active... Или я не правильно делаю? 
Они же могут засекать время нажатия мышкой (протяженность blur). А программно - оно мгновенно. Вот как это все имитировать грамотно - в этом вопрос.

**Вопрос: как имитировать нажатие мышки на чистом JS?**

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь огорчить, но кажется, теперь программно не получится вызвать нужное поведение.

В объекте события есть поле `isTrusted`, которое говорит о том, как именно было вызвано событие: программно или пользователем.

> isTrusted - свойство объекта Event, доступное только на чтение. Принимает значение true, если событие было инициировано действиями пользователя, и false, если событие было создано или изменено скриптом, либо с помощью dispatchEvent

Вот минифицированный код на сайте:

```
// При программном клике проверка не пройдет.
t.isTrusted && this.onVote(e.getAttribute("data-choice"))
```

Итог: они защитились от программных кликов таким образом. Либо нужно как-то получить доступ к скоупу, где есть класс с этим методом `onVote` и вызывать руками его, либо не судьба...

**Полезные ссылки** 
[`event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)

Comment: а если расширение для хрома написать - можно-ли их скрипты изменить?

Comment: @kostia7alania все зависит от того, как именно их скрипт записан, вы например, можете встроить какой-то скрипт на страницу. Но нужно смотреть детальней, как именно добавляется событие + как получить доступ к классу с нужным методом. Именно `js` классу

Comment: Вы смотрите этот скрипт https://pd1eu.badoocdn.com/v2/-/-/js/hon_v3/bundles/base-app.a88195accdd224145ef1.js ?

Comment: ну тут видимо описание компонентов, а вообще обработчик в другом скрипте

Comment: Ура! Я сделал фейковый клик с помощью puppeteer;

Я запустил безголовый CHROME на етот сайт:
https://rude-cause.surge.sh/
кликнул и заскриншотил результат клика ; https://sun9-5.userapi.com/c855036/v855036037/165857/R7nenfutSf8.jpg